# How to send the java variable value to reactJS?

Tags: reactjs, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, postman

I have a reactJS component with submit function as follows -

```
const url = "http://localhost:8083/PasswordResetEmail";
function submit(strEmailIs) {
  axios
    .post(url, {
      email: strEmailIs
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
    });
}
```

through which I am sending email id to backend with following JpaRepository implementation --

```
@Repository
public interface usernameExists extends JpaRepository<user, Long>{
    
    boolean existsByUsername(String userName);
    
}
```

which is returning true in response,which I have stored in a String variable as follows with the help of HttpClient and HttpRequest class as follows -

```
String bool=response.body(); //true
```

Now ,I want to send the bool variable value to reactJS . How should I do it ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: Imagine this problem as two islands one representing front end and second one representing back end, now the solution for the connection of these two islands is some kind of a bridge. Bridge in this case would be requests sent from the front end to back end and in reverse. In this case what you can initially do is set up another API route where you would be sending `GET` request using `axios` from the front end to receive the wanted variable/variables.

Comment: You just mentioned that you DO send it via response, so what are you asking for? Sending it without a request (via sockets)?

Comment: I want to send java variable value to ReactJS .How can I do it?